# How to make a from still showing when data has inserted

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a problem here.
I have made a page with 3 form in there. the form name is.
`#select,#select1, and select2`

at 1st step
when the page load just form `#select` will showing ( i'm done with this),
at 2nd step
when the user has choose the option at the form `#select` just form `#select1` or `#select2` has showing (i'm done with this too),
and the last step (that i need your help guy's)
when the user has clicking my input button  i use this id `#ok` for the button doing refresh and do my input function. nah the problem is i want still showing the form that the user use to input data still showing when the page is reload

I use this code for hide and showing the form `#select,#select1, and select2`.

```js
 $(document).on('click','#close1',function(e){
        $("#select1").hide();
  $("#select").show();
  $('#get_select').val("");
  $('#option3').val("-");
    });
   $(document).on('click','#close2',function(e){
        $("#select2").hide();
  $("#select").show();
  $('#get_select').val("");
  $('#option3').val("-");
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").hide();
 $("#select2").hide();
    $("#select_input").click(function () {
    if ($('#get_select').val()== "In"){
  $("#select1").show();
  $("#select").hide();
 }
 else{
  $("#select2").show();
  $("#select").hide();
 }
   
    });
});
```

and i use this code for inputing data

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).on('click','#ok',function(e){
 if ($('#kadar_air').val() == ''){
  alert ('Kolom Kadar Air Kosong Harap Di Isi');
 }else{
  var data= $("#select1").serialize();
  $.ajax({
   data:data,
   type:"POST",
   url:"../php/ka_in/ka_in.php",
   success: function(data){
    alert ("Data:" + data);
    
   }
  });
 }

 window.location.reload();
 clearInput();
});
$("select1").submit(function(){
 return false;
});
function clearInput(){
 $("#select1 :select1").each( function() {

 $('#date').val('');
 $('#kode_mat').val('');
 $('#nama_mat').val('');
 $('#po').val('');
 $('#kadar_air').val('');
 $('#nama_ppic').val('');
});
}
```

html code for the form that displaying my data

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/ka_in/ka_display_all.php",
  success: function(data){
   var list = JSON.parse(data);
   for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
    var tr = "<tr>";
    
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal1']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['po']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['kode']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['ka']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['ppic']+"</td>";
    
    tr += "</tr>";
    $("#ka_in tbody").append(tr);
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ka_in-content" style=" width:80%; margin-left:170px">

   <div id="pos" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right; width:183px">
   <form action="" id="show_data" class="show_data" name="show_data" method="post">
    <div id="poskiri"  style="float:left; width:90px"><input type="text" id="date1" name="date" size="15" /></div><br />
    <div id="poskanan"  style="float:left; width:90px"><input type="text" id="date2" name="date"  size="15" /></div><br /><br />
    </form>
    <div id="button" style="float:left; width:170px">
 <img src="../image/show.png" class="button" name="popup4" id="popup4" onclick="up4();" style="height:35px; width:40px" />
  <img src="../image/exel.jpg" class="button" name="ex" id="ex" onclick="myFunction1();" style="height:35px; width:40px" />
    <img src="../image/print.png"  class="button" name="print" id="print" class="print" style="height:35px; width:40px;"/>
    <img src="../image/circle_close_delete_-128.png"  class="tutup" name="tutup" id="tutup" style="height:25px; width:30px; " onclick="up1();" />
    </div>
                </div>
                
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:800px;">
                        <div class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:800px">
                             <table id="ka_in" class="table table-bordered" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th >No</th>
                                        <th >Tanggal Masuk</th>
                                        <th >Tanggal Input</th>
                                        <th >PO Number</th>
                                        <th >Kode Material</th>
                                        <th >Nama Material</th>
                                        <th >Kadar Air</th>
                                        <th w>Nama PPIC</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this my php

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");


// Data for Titik1
$sql ="SELECT * FROM ka_in";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Why you want to refresh the page when you send the data using ajax ?!

Comment: when i'm not using refresh my display data would not showing T_T

Comment: Do you mean the data you're getting from the server side ( the data used in this alert : `alert ("Data:" + data)` ?? )

Comment: that alert just for inserting data only.
not for displaying.

Comment: I know but instead of this alert you should display the data somewhere inside you page without refreshing the page... try to add your HTML code and describe more what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki you mean the alert of my data input must be on my page that need to reloading for getting a value from database?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i dont know how to add my html code. cz i use a modul for showing the data that i got from my database

Comment: The `data` returned from the ajax request isn't the data from database ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the data returned from my database. just the alert just showing when the data has successfully inserted

Comment: i will edit my question with my html code and my displaying data code it will be help?

Comment: Yes it will, go ahead.

Comment: i add the html.. sorry when it will break the line or the css. cz i use bootstrap

Comment: I think I got you try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got you, you could add your ajax to a function like :

```
function displayAll() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/ka_in/ka_display_all.php",
    success: function(data){
      var list = JSON.parse(data);
      for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
        var tr = "<tr>";

        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal1']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['po']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['kode']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['ka']+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>" +list[i]['ppic']+"</td>";

        tr += "</tr>";
        $("#ka_in tbody").append(tr);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Then just call it at the top of the script like :

```
displayAll();
```

Then call it when your data was inserted succefully in the success callback like :

```
$.ajax({
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/ka_in/ka_in.php",
    success: function(data){
        alert ("Data:" + data);

        displayAll();
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** You need just one ready function in your document so just open it at the top and put all your scripts inside :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     //You script here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i inserting again the data will be display as multiple..
do i need add `$("ka_in tbody").empty();` ?

Comment: Yes or also `$("#ka_in tbody").html('')` and it should do the trick ;)

Comment: You could add it just before the loop `for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){`

Comment: btw... i want to ask.
can you see my html code? i have two div there contain of two textbox.
can i get the string of that two textbox? (the div inside form `#show_data`)
everytime i use form method then i put a table inside it for get the string from a text box. but this time i try to get string from that textbox with different way. im still use a from but i use a div inside it not a table .

Comment: Achari sorry bro im to much asking T_T. i want to know more about ajax xD

Comment: No worries you could get any "element/value" in the DOM using jQuery. if you mean `date1/date2` you could get them by `id` using `$('#date1').val()/$('#date2').val()`..

Comment: yapz... that's i mean.
i need that to call string for select with a condition in my php.
no problem when i use a div right?

Comment: thx so much for your attention and your answer @Zakaria Acharki.. 
your answer and your explanation give me more experience on jquery

Comment: _no problem when i use a div right?_ No problem, Glad I could help bro anytime :) HAPPY CODING.